# Excel Visual Basic Application-defined or Object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, worksheet-function

So I have two excel worksheets in one workbook. There is a bigger one called "data" and smaller one called "Sheet1." The code below first creates a new sheet called "DailyReport" and compare the two sheets. If one cell from the Column B of the "Sheet1" is the same as one cell in the column B of "data", it should copy that row in "data" to the new sheet "DailyReport." Below is the code. It is a Macro. Now it keeps saying "Invalid procedure call or argument"error.

```
Sub DailyReportGenerator()
Sheets.Add.Name = "DailyReport"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim StartNumber As Integer
Dim EndNumber As Integer
Dim StartNumber2 As Integer

EndNumber = 9999

For StartNumber = 1 To EndNumber
    For StartNumber2 = 1 To EndNumber

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(StartNumber, "B").Value = Worksheets("data").Cells(StartNumber2, "B").Value Then
        Sheets("data").Range(Sheets("data").Cells(StartNumber, "B"), Sheets("data").Cells(StartNumber, "CA")).Copy Sheets("DailyReport").Cells("StartNumber, B")
    End If

    Next StartNumber2
Next StartNumber

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("DailyReportChristina").Range(Sheets("DailyReport")...`  this is your problem.

Comment: also `.Cells(StartNumber, B)` should be `.Cells(StartNumber, "B")`

Comment: @simoco Sorry for the mistake. That is on me. I adjust it. Now it keeps reporting "invalid procedure call or argument" on this line "Sheets("data").Range(Sheets("data").Cells(StartNumber, "B"), Sheets("data").Cells(StartNumber, "CA")).Copy Sheets("DailyReport").Cells("StartNumber, B")"

Comment: change `.Cells("StartNumber, B")` to `.Cells(StartNumber, "B")` (at the end)

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

```
Sub DailyReportGenerator()

Const EndNumber As Long = 999

Dim shtRpt As Worksheet, shtData As Worksheet, shtSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim rwNumSht1 As Long, rwNumData As Long

Set shtRpt = Sheets.Add()
shtRpt.Name = "DailyReport"

Set shtData = Worksheets("data")
Set shtSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For rwNumSht1 = 1 To EndNumber
    For rwNumData = 1 To EndNumber

    If shtSheet1.Cells(rwNumSht1, "B").Value = shtData.Cells(rwNumData, "B").Value Then
        With shtData
        .Range(.Cells(rwNumData, "B"), .Cells(rwNumData, "CA")).Copy _
                                           shtRpt.Cells(rwNumSht1, "B")
        End With
    End If

    Next rwNumData
Next rwNumSht1

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim. thx for helping out. i changed the code but i don't think "with" is the way to go. It keeps outputting error on with.           For StartNumber = 1 To EndNumber
        For StartNumber2 = 1 To EndNumber

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(StartNumber, "B").Value = Worksheets("data").Cells(StartNumber2, "B").Value Then
            With
            Sheets("DailyReport").Range(.Cells(StartNumber, "B"), .Cells(StartNumber, "CA")).Copy Sheets("data").Cells(StartNumber, "B")
            End With
        End If

Comment: thank you so much. the code works well. But one quick answer about VBA (i never coded in it before): does it usually take long time? I have a big file (4000 rows total) and once i start running the program, excel would be freezed for a while to run it. I understand the big-o of the code is bad. But it shouldn't be that bad, right/

Comment: Try setting `Application.Calculation` to manual - that should give you some additional speed-up. Don't forget to set it back to automatic at the end of the Sub.  If you need really fast execution then you need to switch to using Variant arrays or some kind of lookup like a `Scripting.Dictionary` object